# Can anybody please provide me with a list of the characters and their corresponding handles from Durarara!! & Durarara!! ×2?

Tags: durarara

I was wondering if anybody has a list of the characters spanning both the anime version of "Durarara!!" and the anime version of "Durarara!! ×2", along with each character's corresponding online handle (for the chatroom, AND for the Dollars website for the characters it applies to) ? If a character from the anime doesn't have an online handle, then please include them in the list without a handle by their real name. A nicely organized list format would be most appreciated, if it's not too much trouble.  It would also be greatly appreciated if you were to state the colour of each character's handle next to it as well (I have difficulty reading kanji, so it's easy for me to lose track of who's who when they don't say each other's handle), please and thank you. Lastly, if you could please also state the character's colour gang affiliation (as well as if they were possessed by Saika) beside their name where applicable (except for any who are in the dollars, as that will already be taken care of in the above-mentioned Dollars site handle part of the list)? It'll really help me to be able to keep up with everything that goes on in the anime.

Here's an example of the sort of thing I'm looking for:
Mikado Ryuugamine - Chatroom Handle: TarouTanaka (田中太郎, Blue) - Dollars Handle: _______ (______, _____)

Masaomi Kida (Yellow Scarves) - Bacura (バキュラ, _____)